# Rounds of MD5 and SHA512 Hashing Algorithms

Tags: hash, cryptography, md5, sha

What is the exact number of rounds employed by the MD5 and SHA512 hashing algorithms?

According to various sources, the SHA512 hashing algorithm employs a total of 80 rounds (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA2).

On the other hand, I am confused when it comes to the MD5 hashing algorithm. According to Wikipedia, MD5 employs 64 rounds (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA2). However, another website states that MD5 employs 4 rounds (http://md5live.com/2013/03/06/encryption-methods-sha1-vs-md5-vs-sha256/). Who is the correct of the two please?

I can't seem to find a reliable source of information regarding the number of rounds. Furthermore, what are these rounds exactly? In simple terms, what does the hashing algorithm do during these rounds? Thank you very much :))

Comment: This is a question for http://crypto.stackexchange.com, but only after sufficient study; hashes are standardized, look up the standards documents.

Comment: Don't [cross post](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39420/rounds-of-md5-and-sha512-hashing-algorithms)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about cryptography, not about programming. It has also been posted and answered at http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39420/rounds-of-md5-and-sha512-hashing-algorithms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MD5 is defined in [RFC 1321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1321) which talks about 4 rounds. So MD5 has 4 rounds. Those rounds are however made up of 16 similar calculations, so it may be easier to implement in 4 * 16 = 64 rounds. Because of these similar calculations - without any additional calculations between them - the line between a calculation and a round becomes blurred. If unsure, keep to the standard.

Note that with most newer hash functions the move is towards many small rounds. In this respect, it is probably *easier* to think of MD5 as 64 rounds to have a fair comparison.

Comment: Thank you so much for the information owlstead :)  I appreciate it immensely :)